# Get string after ',' delimeter comma or special characters

Tags: postgresql, split

The field name is `message`, table name is `log`.

Data Examples:

Values for message:

```
"(wsname,cmdcode,stacode,data,order_id) values (hyd-l904149,2,1,,1584425657892);"
"(wsname,cmdcode,stacode,data,order_id) values (hyd-l93mt54,2,1,,1584427657892);"
(command_execute,order_id,workstation,cmdcode,stacode,application_to_kill,application_parameters) values  (kill, 1583124192811, hyd-psag314, 10, 2, tsws.exe,  -u production ); "
```

and in log table i need to get separated column wsname with values as hyd-l904149 and hyd-l93mt54 and hyd-psag314, column cmdcode with values  as 2,2 and 10 and column stacode with values as 1,1 and 2, e.g.:

```
wsname        cmdcode   stacode
hyd-l904149   2         1
hyd-l93mt54   2         1
hyd-psag314   10        2
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: are you looking for select statement? did your message column contains values with comma separated? If yes then you can use split_part to get separated value

Comment: It might be much easier to change the code that _writes_ the log table to store that information as a JSONB value using key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_matches` to extract left and right part of `values` clause, then `regexp_split_to_array` to split these parts by commas, then filter rows containing `wsname` using `= any(your_array)` construct, then `select` required columns from array.

Or - alternative solution - fix data to be syntactically valid part of `insert` statement, create auxiliary tables, insert data into them and then just select.

Answer (score 0):

As in comment section I mentioned about inbuilt function in posgressql

> split_part(string,delimiter, field_number)

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb1df/1

Answer (score 0):

As the json capabilities of the un-supported version 9.3 are very limited, I would [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createextension.html) the [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) extension, and then do it like this:

```
select coalesce(vals -> 'wsname', vals -> 'workstation') as wsname, 
       vals -> 'cmdcode' as cmdcode,
       vals -> 'stacode' as stacode
from (
  select hstore(regexp_split_to_array(e[1], '\s*,\s*'), regexp_split_to_array(e[2], '\s*,\s*')) as vals
  from log l, 
    regexp_matches(l.message, '\(([^\)]+)\)\s+values\s+\(([^\)]+)\)') as x(e)
) t
```

`regexp_matches()` splits the message into two arrays: one for the list of column names and one for the matching values. These arrays are used to create a key/value pair so that I can access the value for each column by the column name.

If you know that the positions of the columns are always the same, you can remove the use of the `hstore` type. But that would require quite a huge CASE expression to test where the actual columns appear.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=45de92bc2f1094e0eeadae2dfb4f405c)

With a modern, supported version of Postgres, I would use `jsonb_object(text[], text[])` passing the two arrays resulting from the `regexp_matches()` call.